# C# XML adding/copying

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

With the following XML I am trying to copy and add to another XML but I haven't used the C# XML document objects before.  So here is the XML

```
<config>
   <configXML>
      <Connections>
         <Connection excyptedConnection="encrypted string">
      </Connections>
   <configXML>
</config>
```

I want to be able to copy out the Connection or add new Connection information.  I want to be able to use the /config/configXML/Connections/ xpath for adding/copying the values.

Anyone that can help?

Thanks

Comment: XPATH will let you query the file but not write to it.  What environment are you using?  Java, C#, etc?

Comment: Are you using C# 3 or higher? If so you could use XDocument or XElement and LINQ to XML.

Comment: I'm using C#, I put it in the title.  Sorry if you didn't see.  Could I get the location to write to from the xpath?  Thanks

Comment: BTW, this snippet of XML is invalid ... Connection has no closing tag, and the configXML closing tag is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var path = "c:\\temp\\myXml.xml";       
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("config/configXML/Connections/Connection");
element.Attribute("encryptedConnection").Value = "Whatever";    
doc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use nifty constructs like Linq for Xml etc., if all you need is to change the value of one (or few) node, just use the [XmlDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_members.aspx).
It exposes your XML's DOM and provides a simple set of functions to get and manipulate values.

You can either load your XML as a string, or from a file. And there are plenty of samples floating around.

Comment: I'd question this being simpler. Care to post a code sample comparable to Richard Hein's?

Comment: I could, but it would probably look very similar to Richard's code.